# Pass data to Card

Tags: laravel-nova

In the docs it says that you can pass data via `withMeta` method
https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/customization/cards.html#registering-cards

My question is: how can I get it in `Card.vue` file?

I have tried to reach them like so:

```js
mounted() {
    console.log(this.currentVisitors)
    console.log(this.card.currentVisitors)
},
```

but both output `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call that method when you are registering the card. More info: https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/1270